# Inequality with mean inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $a,b,c > 0$ and $a+b+c = 18 abc$, prove that
> $$\sqrt{3 +\frac{1}{a^{2}}}+\sqrt{3 +\frac{1}{b^{2}}}+\sqrt{3 +\frac{1}{c^{2}}}\geq 9$$

I started writing the left member as $\frac{\sqrt{3a^{2}+ 1}}{a}+ \frac{\sqrt{3b^{2}+ 1}}{b} + \frac{\sqrt{3c^{2}+ 1}}{c}$ and I applied AM-QM inequality, but I obtain something with $\sqrt[4]{3}$.

Comment: Use Minkowski's Inequality and finish off with rearrangement inequality, similar to solutions to Problem 682 here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h299899p3084827

Comment: If I am not wrong, threads containing answers to this question got deleted $2$ times.

Comment: Is there a typo in third radical, which now matches second? [should its $b^2$ really be $c^2$]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sqrt{3 +\frac{1}{a^{2}}}+\sqrt{3 +\frac{1}{b^{2}}}+\sqrt{3 +\frac{1}{b^{2}}}$$
$$
= \sqrt{
9 +
\frac{1}{a^{2}} + 
\frac{1}{b^{2}} +
\frac{1}{c^{2}} + 
2\sum_{cyc}
{\sqrt{
\left(3 +
\frac{1}{a^{2}}\right)
\left(3 +\frac{1}{b^{2}}\right)}}
}
$$
$$\tag{By C-S}\geqslant \sqrt{9 +
\frac{1}{a^{2}} + 
\frac{1}{b^{2}} +
\frac{1}{c^{2}} + 
2\sum_{cyc}{3 + \frac{1}{ab}}}$$
$$= \sqrt{9 +
\frac{1}{a^{2}} + 
\frac{1}{b^{2}} +
\frac{1}{c^{2}} + 
54}$$
$$\geqslant \sqrt{9 +18 + 54} =\sqrt{81} = 9$$
Which uses $\frac{1}{ab} + \frac{1}{bc} + \frac{1}{ca} = 18$ and $\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2} \geqslant \frac{1}{ab} + \frac{1}{bc} + \frac{1}{ca}$.

Comment: can you clarify the C-S step?

Comment: nice!(+1) but @cosmo5  that step is right and self explanatory

Comment: @cosmo5 If you are thinking of applying C-S on $\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt{\left(3 +\frac{1}{a^{2}}\right)\left(3 +\frac{1}{b^{2}}\right)}}$, think of applying C-S to each term in that sum, not on entire sum.

Answer (score 5):

let $x=\frac{1}{a},y=\frac{1}{b},z=\frac{1}{c}$
$$xy+yz+zx=18 \tag{given}$$
$$\color{red}{x+y+z\ge 3\sqrt{6}} \tag1$$

notice that $${(x-\sqrt{6})}^2\ge 0\Rightarrow \sqrt{3+x^2}\ge \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}x+1$$

Thus $$\sum \sqrt{3+x^2}\ge \sum \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}x+1\ge\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\color{red}{3\sqrt{6}}+3=9$$

Note the inequality marked $(1)$ is left as an exercise

Comment: Very nice! ($+1$) Only the last equality should be inequality.

Answer (score 3):

From Minkowski inequality: $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} + \sqrt{y^2 + b^2} \ge \sqrt{(x + y)^2 + (a + b)^2}$

applied to the first two terms, with the notation of @Albus, we get:
$\sqrt{\sqrt{3}^2 +x^2} + \sqrt{\sqrt{3}^2 +y^2} \ge \sqrt{(2\sqrt{3})^2 + (x+ y)^2}$. Let's denote RHS of the inequality by $X$.

Then, apply Minkowski inequality again to $ X + \sqrt{3 + z^2}$, to obtain:
$\sqrt{27 + (x + y + z)^2} \ge 9$, which is equivalent to (1) from @Albus Dumbledore's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Put Let $a=\frac{x}{3\sqrt2},$ $b=\frac{y}{3\sqrt2}$ and $c=\frac{z}{3\sqrt2}.$

And $x=\tan(u)$,$y=\tan(v)$,$z=\tan(w)$ with $u+v+w=\pi$

Then the function $f(u)=\sqrt{3+\frac{18}{\tan(u)^2}}$ is convex on $(0,\pi)$ see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second%20derivative%20sqrt%283%2B18%2Ftan%28x%29%C2%B2%29)

Remains to apply Jensen's inequality .

Comment: How do you get the idea to conver to trigonometry? 
In a middle / high-school contest, I find taking the second derivative of f(u) a bit challenging.